# Could not find :billing-5.2.1 - Unity as a library

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity As a Library. Everything was fine till I add In-App-Puchese. I have bunch of errors in Android Studio while I am trying to compile.

Looks like there is a problem with libs from unity. I have the file billing-5.2.1.aar in libs folder, though.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation(name: 'billing-5.2.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'common', ext:'aar')

}
```

[image]

**And the errors...**

FAILURE: Build completed with 8 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find :billing-5.2.1:.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :unityLibrary
> Could not find :common:.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :unityLibrary

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
  java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
  Cause 1: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find :billing-5.2.1:.
  Required by:
  project :app > project :unityLibrary
  Cause 2: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find :common:.
  Required by:
  project :app > project :unityLibrary

==============================================================================

### 3: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find :billing-5.2.1:.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :unityLibrary
> Could not find :common:.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :unityLibrary

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)

  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
  Cause 1: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find :billing-5.2.1:.
  Required by:
  project :app > project :unityLibrary
  Cause 2: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find :common:.
  Required by:
  project :app > project :unityLibrary

==============================================================================

### 4: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find :billing-5.2.1:.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :unityLibrary
> Could not find :common:.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :unityLibrary

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
  java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
  Cause 1: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find :billing-5.2.1:.
  Required by:
  project :app > project :unityLibrary
  Cause 2: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find :common:.
  Required by:
  project :app > project :unityLibrary

==============================================================================

### 5: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find :billing-5.2.1:.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :unityLibrary
> Could not find :common:.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :unityLibrary

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the lines;

```
implementation(name: 'billing-5.2.1', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'common', ext:'aar')
```

to

```
 api fileTree(include: ['*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
```

That solved my problem.